# Why $\dim \{(X^3-X)Q(X): Q\in\mathbb{R}_{n-3}[X]\}=\dim\mathbb{R}_{n-3}[X]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an endomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{R}_n[X]$. Explicitly,

$$f(P) = (X^2 − X + 1)P(−1) + (X^3 − X)P(0) + (X^3 + X^2 + 1)P(1),$$ for $P\in\mathbb{R}_n[X]$.

I calculated $\ker f$ and found it equal to:

$$\ker f=\{(X^3-X)Q(X): Q\in\mathbb{R}_{n-3}[X]\}.$$

Now, I need to calculate the dimension of $\ker f$ but I could not. I have seen a solution that says $\dim\ker f=\dim \{(X^3-X)Q(X): Q\in\mathbb{R}_{n-3}[X]\}=\dim\mathbb{R}_{n-3}[X]$ but I did not understand it.

Why is

$$\dim \ker f=\dim \{(X^3-X)Q(X): Q\in\mathbb{R}_{n-3}[X]\}=\dim\mathbb{R}_{n-3}[X]=n-2$$
?

Comment: What do polynomials have to do with the kernel  of an endomorphism of a $\mathbf R$-vector space? We're missing some information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an isomorphism
\begin{align}
\mathbf R_{n-3}[X]&\longrightarrow \ker f\\
Q(X)&\longmapsto (X^3-X)Q(X)
\end{align}
and isomorphic vector spaces have the same dimension, hence $\;\dim\ker f=\dim\mathbf R_{n-3}[X]$.

Comment: Why is this isomorphism?

Comment: It's injective because there is no zero-divisor in $\mathbf R[X]$, and surjective because of your description of $\ker f$.